# Get-WmiObject : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, cmd

I've created the following PowerShell script to kill a process:

```
$oProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%G:\\TCAFiles\\Users\\Admin\\2155\\Unturned.exe%'";foreach ($oProc in $oProcs){Stop-Process $oProc.Handle}
```

The above script works fine, however when I'm trying to make the script start from Command Prompt it fails.

```
powershell -Mta -NoProfile -Command "$oProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%G:\TCAFiles\Users\Admin\2155\Unturned.exe%'";foreach ($oProc in $oProcs){Stop-Process $oProc.Handle}"
```

This results in the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'%G:\TCAFiles\Users\Admin\2155\Unturned.ex e%'.
At line:1 char:11
+ $oProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter commandline like '%G:\T ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it.

Comment: Your issue is with unescaped double quotes. But it would be easier to use `Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -eq 'G:\TCAFiles\Users\Admin\ \2155\Unturned.exe'} | Stop-Process` or just `Get-Process Unturned | Stop-Process`

Comment: You don't need to run it from `cmd.exe`. Run it from the PowerShell prompt instead.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to escape any double quotes inside the powershell code that you are passing as an argument. At the moment your command argument will end after "-filter ".

If you are running this from cmd you can escape the double quotes using a backslash:

```
powershell -Mta -NoProfile -Command "$oProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter \"commandline like '%G:\TCAFiles\Users\Admin\2155\Unturned.exe%'\";foreach ($oProc in $oProcs){Stop-Process $oProc.Handle}"
```

Or if you are running this in powershell you can escape them by prepending it with a backtick or another double quote:

```
powershell -Mta -NoProfile -Command "$oProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter ""commandline like '%G:\TCAFiles\Users\Admin\2155\Unturned.exe%'"";foreach ($oProc in $oProcs){Stop-Process $oProc.Handle}"
```

Comment: You're the best! First time I saw someone explain that there are different ways to  escape the quotes in powershell and cmd. Me, I was just about to ask the same question, even though I tried to escape quotes in cmd ... but using the escape method from powershell :(